# Why isn't Express using a JavaScript to bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently getting my feet wet using Express. To start out, I used `express-generator` to scaffold a simple app.

While examining the project, I noticed that the `npm start` command is mapped to a binary (`bin/www`). Upon further inspection I noticed that this file actually contains code to be executed in Node, hence the `#!/usr/bin/env node` pragma. For anyone having a deeper understanding of Express/Node the answer may be obvious, but still I am wondering: Why didn't they simply use a `.js` file to bootstrap the framework. That file could then be run using `node www.js`, I imagine.

Comment: I think you should ask this at [Express Generator repo](https://github.com/expressjs/generator)

Comment: It's common for executables to omit the file extension, regardless of the language they are written in. For example, you run `webpack`, not `node webpack.js`.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few reasons why the script was made an executable

- npm scripts can be mapped to execute local JS files in the project or executables on the system.
- By mapping `npm start` to `bin/www` it is effectively the same as running `./bin/www` on the command line with the important distinction that by running it via a `npm start`, it will also work cross platform (e.g. on systems that ignore the hashbang statement, like Windows), otherwise you would need to run it as `node bin/www` on those systems.
- There's a binary ready to add to startup scripts.